# Change "new"/"newest questions" to "recent"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, navigation, new-nav

The default tab, called "new" isn't actually new, but recently active questions instead (for example: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) is being shown under the new/all tags/all/recently active).

[image: this is like very old...]

Also, the tool tip for this tab doesn't fit, as it says "Recently active or interesting questions". I'm not exactly sure what kind of questions this selects (seems like the old homepage/active) but the name doesn't represent what it says, as there are many on that list that are interesting or new.

Comment: It's "new" as in new activity... right? And then you can further break that down into "recently active" which is the default or "new" meaning questions that were just asked. I don't see a problem with the title, personally. Without it, we'd end up having to add back "New" for the **actually** new questions.

Comment: @Catija that isn't consistent with other naming. "New" questions/answer has always been "recently created", and what you call "new activity" it has always been called "recent activity". Such seems to be the meaning elsewhere on the new question list.

Comment: Maybe if you added some images that would help? Which instance of "new" do you think should be changed and what do you think should should be done with the questions actually called "new" if you change "new" to "recent"?

Comment: @Catija added..

Comment: OK, that's what I thought you meant but the image definitely helps. I think the issue is the narrow definition of "new" of the old system and the fact that SE seems to be broadening the definition of "new" in the new system. Yes, it's the tab called "new" but it contains both the brand new questions and the "recently active" questions that are new in the sense I mentioned before "new activity". As you can see, you're in the sort group "recently active" and the other sort here is "new"... which limits the order to the newly-asked questions, rather than "new activity".

Comment: What about "latest" instead of "recent"? This avoids the duplication of both "recent" and "new" in the sort groups.  So the tab would read "latest" and the sort groups would remain "recently active" and "newest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time we rename a tab, this introduces discomfort for some people (see "change aversion"). This tab was originally called "recommended" but we renamed it due to popular demand. There seem to be many less calls for change with "new" so we are going to keep it for now to see if it grows on people or not.

Answer (score 0):

Recent would still not significantly sense the brand new question. Recent is good to use with an activity and activity could be many thing but not just to asking a question. I would suggest to have a bold font with a color that way it is easy to deliver too.